# Какие технологии нужно знать для хорошей back-end разработки на Node.js?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Какие технологии нужно знать для хорошей back-end разработки на Node.js?
Касающиеся работы протоколов, настроек сервера и как что устроено.

Выразился бы точнее, но если бы мог, то не спрашивал.

Занимаюсь front-end. Пишу на JavaScript, изучаю Node.js. Но понимаю что нужно знать как что работает. Протоколы и прочее.

Что нужно знать? Что посоветуете почитать?

P.S. Не беру в расчет базы данных, фреймворки ипроче.